# Hover to show/hide div

Tags: php, jquery, hover

I have a page to show multiple images and when hover some div contains information with show above the image. I show the image from directories by looping.

I used jquery to handle the hover but the effect doesnt show.
Anyone can help?

html/php

```
<?php
//to show remaining images by looping
$dir = dir("images");
while($filename=$dir->read()) {

    if($filename == "." || $filename == ".." || $filename == $first_image) continue;

     echo "<div class='cp-thumb'>";

     echo "<div class='cp-hover' style='display: none;' ><div class='cpHover-bg'></div>
            <div class='cpHover-info'><p class='text11'>".$newDatetime."</p><p class='text10'>".$caption."</p></div></div>"; 
     echo "<img src='images/".$filename."'class='img_235x235' />
     </div>";
```

jquery:

```
<script>
    $(".cp-thumb").hover(
          function () {
            $(".cp-hover").show();
          }, 
          function () {
            $(".cp-hover").hide();
          }
        );
</script>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Can you add your html as well? or create a JsFiddle

Comment: what is the relationship betweern cp-thumb and cp-hover

Comment: @ArunPJohny it's actually the thumbnail to show the image, the cp-hover is a div that i want to show when mouseover the cp-thumb

Comment: The jquery seems fine from what you've added (so-far), so the problem most probably lies with your HTML or CSS.

Comment: Wrap your code in $(function() { <your code goes here> }; to see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CSS Solution**: 
You can handle this situation without jQuery at all. You can use CSS only by a simple code line

```
.cp-thumb:hover .cp-hover { display:block; }
```

example - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zEJVK/6/)

**jQuery Solution:**

its should be written like this example - http://jsfiddle.net/zEJVK/

```
$(".box").hover(
     function() {
         $(".box2").show() 
     }, 
     function() {
         $(".box2").hide();
     }
);
```

**Update**: I've updated the code, depend on what is the structure, you can use `$(this)` 
example - http://jsfiddle.net/zEJVK/1/

This example is selecting the closest `div` to the hovered element and shows it. you can use `children` or `parent` and familiar function methods to show your relevant element.

**Another update**:
http://jsfiddle.net/zEJVK/3/
If the Thumb elemnt is the parent, you should use `children` method, example posted

```
$(".cp-thumb").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).children(".cp-hover").show();
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).children(".cp-hover").hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: but i found the problem is, I loop the div so that i have many div have the same name which is cp-thumb. how do I give different name to the looped div so that it can recognize which div to show hover function?

Comment: can you post the structure of your divs?

Comment: It is in the html/php code, maybe it is quite messy, let me explain. the cp-thumb is a div that looped to show images and the cp-hover is the div i wan to show when mouseover into cp-thumb. sorry for that im still learning =)

Comment: Yes I understand what you are saying, but it depends on what is the output of your HTML. maybe you can use `this` inside the function. see update.

Comment: I had update to show my output in my question, im not sure, the this didnt function.

Comment: updated the code in `jsfiddle` (changed the classes for you comfort)

Comment: It's works!!!!!!!!!! but another problem appeared... as u can see i have many div have the same name which is the cp-thumb, so when i mouseover, everydiv show up the hover but not only the div that i pointed to... anything i can do? ^^

Comment: I'm glad its works for you. The `children` method can filter the the children by a selector. You can write a specific class you want to show, just as I wrote in my example. here is updated example with several `cp-thumbs` - http://jsfiddle.net/zEJVK/5/

Comment: My code is same with urs but i dont knw why it dont work like what u do in jsfiddle =( for mine, when i mouseover to one div, all divs change color =(

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cp-thumb").hover(
      function () {
        $(".cp-hover").show();
      }, 
      function () {
        $(".cp-hover").hide();
      }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use relative queries to find `cp-hover`, in this case you need to find the `cp-hover` element which is a child of the hovered `cp-thumb` element

```
<script>
    $(".cp-thumb").hover(
          function () {
            $(this).find(".cp-hover").show();
          }, 
          function () {
            $(this).find(".cp-hover").hide();
          }
        );
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this code and I find out all the image named cp-thumb. I think this is why the jquery dont work. May I know how do I find the targeted cp-thumb?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`

```
$(".cp-thumb").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".cp-hover").show();
});

$(".cp-thumb").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".cp-hover").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using

```
    
        $(".cp-thumb").live('hover',function () {
                $(this).find(".cp-hover").show();
              }, 
              function () {
                $(this).find(".cp-hover").hide();
              }
         );
    

    
        $("body").delegate(".cp-thumb", "hover",         
              function () {
                $(this).find(".cp-hover").show();
              }, 
              function () {
                $(this).find(".cp-hover").hide();
              });
    

    
        $("body").on("click", ".cp-thumb",         
              function () {
                $(this).find(".cp-hover").show();
              }, 
              function () {
                $(this).find(".cp-hover").hide();
              });
```

You could also check it from :
http://justprogrammer.com/2013/06/25/jquery-basic-concepts/

Comment: Could you please make Jfiddle for that...

or you could also try
`code
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".cp-thumb").hover(
      function () {
        $(".cp-hover").show();
      }, 
      function () {
        $(".cp-hover").hide();
      }
    );
});
`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/J43X6/

In your script you should wrap your function with

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```